# Hide and Show Children if Radio Button is Checked

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Basically I have several fields resembling the code below The fieldset class "depends" is originally hidden from view. What I am looking for is if the user select Yes (The class options_check) then the class "depends" will show. I can get all of the class "depends" to show when yes is clicked but I only want one to show at a time. I hope that make sense. Here is what I have so far but right now but it does not work. Thanks in advance for steering me in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.depends').hide();
$('.options_check').click(function(){
    //If Options_check is Clicked
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent('.radio_options').children('.depends').show();
        }
    });

});


<fieldset class="radio_options">
    <label for="siblings">Do You Have Any Siblings ?: <em>*</em></label>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="yes_siblings">Yes I have siblings</label>
        <input class="options_check" name="siblings" type="radio" value="yes I have siblings" <?php if(isset($_POST['siblings']) && $_POST['siblings'] == 'yes I have siblings') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="no_siblings">No siblings</label>
        <input name="siblings" type="radio" value="no siblings"<?php if(isset($_POST['siblings']) && $_POST['siblings'] == 'no siblings') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="depends">
        <label for="how_many_siblings">How Many Siblings ? <em>*</em></label>
        <?php howManySiblings($grades); ?>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<!--END SIBLINGS-->

<fieldset class="radio_options">
    <label for="lived_in_english_country">Have You Ever Lived in an English Speaking Country: <em>*</em></label>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="yes_english_country">Yes I have lived in a English speaking country</label>
        <input class="options_check" name="lived_in_english_country" type="radio" value="I have lived in an English country"<?php if(isset($_POST['lived_in_english_country']) && $_POST['lived_in_english_country'] == 'I have lived in an English country') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="no_english_country">No I have not lived in a English speaking country</label>
        <input name="lived_in_english_country" type="radio" value="no I have not lived in an English country" <?php if(isset($_POST['lived_in_english_country']) && $_POST['lived_in_english_country'] == 'no I have not lived in an English country') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="depends">
        <label for="which_english_country">Which Country/Countries ? <em>*</em></label>
        <input name="which_english_country" type="text" value="<?php echo $which_english_country ?>">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="depends">
        <label for="how_long_in_english_country">How Long <em>*</em></label>
        <input name="how_long_in_english_country" type="text" value="<?php echo $how_long_in_english_country ?>">
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
          <!--END ENGLISH SPEAKING COUNTRY-->
```

Comment: So when the input `options_check` is checked, you would like the fieldset with class `depends`to be visible, and when the other option is checked, you want it to not be visible?

Comment: here is working fiddle,, http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/xsM9z/1/ .. is this what you need

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do however If i use the value name then that only applys to specific example. I have multiple versions of the above So I am looking for something generic that will only hide and show the child .depends of parent .radio_options so I don't have to rite the code over and over again changing out the values. I have update my question to reflect what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend setting the display style of the `depends` fieldset to none. This means it won't be visible to start with, and is better to do that here, than when the javascript loads. Better still would be to add the `display:none;` to `fieldset.depends` in an external CSS file.

```
<fieldset class="depends" style="display:none;">
    <label for="how_many_siblings">How Many Siblings ? <em>*</em></label>
    <?php howManySiblings($grades); ?>
</fieldset>
```

Then, on the jQuery side, I think the best thing is to listen for the change event on the outer fieldset. You can then see if the input is checked, and if it is, toggle the `depends` fieldset. Here's the code:

```
$('fieldset.radio_options').change(function(e){
    var yesChecked = $(this).find('input.options_check').is(':checked');
    var dependsFieldset = $(this).children('fieldset.depends');
    dependsFieldset.toggle(yesChecked);
});
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsM9z/4/).

Comment: That worked! Exactly what I was looking for thank you so much! Never would have though to try it that way

Comment: Glad to hear it! It looks like you may be planning to check the initial state of the radio buttons. If so, have a look at this modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsM9z/5/) for the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

here is working code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/xsM9z/1/)

Html:

```
<fieldset class="radio_options">
<label for="siblings">Do You Have Any Siblings ?: <em>*</em></label>
<fieldset>
    <label for="yes_siblings">Yes I have siblings</label>
    <input class="options_check" name="siblings" type="radio" value="yes I have siblings" >
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="no_siblings">No siblings</label>
    <input name="siblings" class="options_check" type="radio"  >
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="depends">
    <label for="how_many_siblings">How Many Siblings ? <em>*</em></label>
    <?php howManySiblings($grades); ?>
</fieldset>
```

Javscript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.depends').hide();
  $('.options_check').click(function(){
  //If Options_check is Clicked

   if($(this).is(':checked') && $.trim($(this).val()) == $.trim("yes I have siblings"))
   {
     $('.depends').show();
   }
   else{
    $('.depends').hide();
   }

 });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution, but I am looking for a way to target the class "depends" without having to specify the value each time so I can use it multiple times for different form inputs